# Set input value of textbox correctly using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website with a Username textbox and a Password textbox and a Sign in button for login. On that website if I login by entering the username and password manually, it works fine. But when I do it using JS like this

```
document.getElementById('userId').value = 'name';
document.getElementById('pwd').value = 'password';
```

And click the login button, it shows error "Please enter a username and password for login", i.e. it's not picking up the values.

I also tried despatching the event like this but no luck

```
var username = document.getElementById('userId');
username.value = 'name';

if ('createEvent' in document) {
  var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
  evt.initEvent('change', false, true);
  username.dispatchEvent(evt);
} else {
  username.fireEvent('onchange');
}

var password = document.getElementById('pwd');
password.value = 'password';

if ('createEvent' in document) {
  var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
  evt.initEvent('change', false, true);
  password.dispatchEvent(evt);
} else {
  password.fireEvent('onchange');
}
```

So my only question to experts out here is what should be the Javascript/JQuery code that I can write which will blueprint the logic of changing the textbox value manually.

Comment: Where is HTML code?

Comment: Do your inputs shows assigned value? Do you validate input values before sending request?

Comment: @dhaker This is the website URL : https://www.irctc.co.in/nget/train-search. Click on "Login" link on top and the login page appears.

Comment: I think the problem is elsewhere. Can you see the textbox changes when you do it via JS? See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b95e1pvr/11/) example for working code via JS

Comment: @MahßußMØøn that's what surprising me more. There are no textbox changes neither by doing it via JS nor via typing manually

Comment: The site is built with angular. I don't think you can change the value in the scope by just assigning value to the input DOM element.

Comment: @squgeim Not only I think I can do this, but also I did it. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I was able to get the job done by just a small change. Instead of firing onchange event, I had to fire oninput event. I figured this out by Chrome Developer Tool as I saw in Event listeners tab that no "change" event was associated with textbox. Instead, it had "input" event. So the following code fixed it :)

```
var username = document.getElementById('userId');
username.value = 'name';

if ('createEvent' in document) {
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent('input', false, true);
username.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
else {
username.fireEvent('oninput');
}

var password = document.getElementById('pwd');
password.value = 'password';

if ('createEvent' in document) {
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent('input', false, true);
password.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
else {
password.fireEvent('oninput');
}
```